# Does "access your data on all websites" apply to only the app tab/window, or browser-wide?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

Many Chrome Web Store apps request this - does it mean the app can access data in all tabs and windows opened in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an extension that requests this permission can view the contents of all open tabs.

Comment: wow, why on earth would anyone ever install an extension/app that allows this?

Comment: We're introducing a new permission called activeTab, which only allows temporary access to the current tab. Some extensions, such as Amazon Shopping, need to see all tabs so that they can make recommendations when you visit a page.

Comment: This is exactly what I ask myself every time I see that dialog and shake my head in disgust, and then hit "cancel"

Comment: [This page](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/chrome-plugins-access-all-data-browsing-activity/) explains that yes, it can do this, but that it's required for even a very simple add-on. And that actually firefox plugins actually have much wider access (to data on your computer, for example), but don't give the same warning. If you don't trust the plugin author, don't install it.